# Is there any benefit to using Lucene's UpdateDocument over Delete then Add?

Tags: lucene

Lucene has an UpdateDocument method on IndexWriter, which will delete existing document(s) and add a new one. Is there any benefit to using this method over explicitly calling DeleteDocuments and then calling AddDocument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atomicity. `update` is atomic while `delete`+`add` are separate, isolated, calls.